# How to update RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have `RecyclerView`, and i can add items from another activity, when item is added to `SQLite DB` it returns me to **StartActivity** where i have my fragment with `RecyclerView` which load my `List<Items>` from  `SQLite DB` ,  but Fragment didnt update , it updated only when i starts another activity

**Fragment:**

```
public class MyCardsFragment extends Fragment {
public DataBaseAdapter data;

private static final String TAG = "MyApp";

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
DataBaseAdapter dataBaseHelper;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_cards, container, false);


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycleView);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());

    dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseAdapter(getActivity());

    recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecycleViewAdapter(dataBaseHelper.getData(),R.layout.custom_row));


    recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

    return view;

}

}
```

This line : `recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();` didnt work
How i can do fast update of my recyclerView?

**Edit:**

**DataBaseAdapter** `getData` :

```
........


public List<Cards> getData(){
        //рабочий лист
        List<Cards> list = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase= helper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor= sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(helper.QUERY,null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        int index0=cursor.getColumnIndex(helper.UID);

        int index1=cursor.getColumnIndex(helper.KEY_NAME);
        int index2=cursor.getColumnIndex(helper.KEY_VALUE);
        int index3=cursor.getColumnIndex(helper.KEY_FORMAT);
        int index4=cursor.getColumnIndex(helper.KEY_COUNTRY);
        int index5=cursor.getColumnIndex(helper.KEY_CARD_HOLDER_NAME);
        int index6=cursor.getColumnIndex(helper.KEY_CARD_RATING);
        int index7=cursor.getColumnIndex(helper.KEY_VOTES_COUNT);
        int index8=cursor.getColumnIndex(helper.KEY_RATED);
        int index9=cursor.getColumnIndex(helper.KEY_CARD_IN_BASE_ID);
        int index11=cursor.getColumnIndex(helper.KEY_CARD_DELETED_OR_NOT);

        int cid = cursor.getInt(index0);
        String name = cursor.getString(index1);
        String value = cursor.getString(index2);
        String format = cursor.getString(index3);
        String country = cursor.getString(index4);
        String holderName = cursor.getString(index5);
        String cardRating = cursor.getString(index6);
        String votesCount = cursor.getString(index7);
        String rated = cursor.getString(index8);
        String cardIdInBase = cursor.getString(index9);
        String deletedOrNot = cursor.getString(index11);

        Cards cards = new Cards(cid,name,format,value,country,holderName,cardRating,cardIdInBase,votesCount,rated,deletedOrNot);

        list.add(cards);

    }

    return list;

}
```

......

Comment: can you share your getdata() code, and how much record is it fetching?

Comment: @Fahim my english is now so good i didnt understand what u mean in your question

Comment: When are you calling `getData`? Try calling `notifiyDataSetChanged` right before `return list;`

Comment: @PedroOliveira i call getData in onCreateView in fragment

Comment: Show us your `RecycleViewAdapter` code

Comment: Try and call notifyDataSetChanged() from inside your adapter class after you have updated the dataset.

Comment: FYI: notifiyDataSetChanged() seems to behave different on on 21 vs 22 release.  It seems I can change everything from 21 to 22 but keep in gradle: **compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.+'** -- still investigating.

Answer (score 1):

Try add 
`adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, adapter.getItemCount());`
in onResume method. `adapter` is `RecycleViewAdapter` which you set into your `RecyclerView`

Comment: Or simply adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() :)